# Gmail API cannot get email data

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I am trying to print my email messages using the gmail API:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()

messages = results.get('messages', [])

if not messages:
    print("No messages found.")
else:
    count = 0 
    for message in messages:
        count += 1

        msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()

        full_msg = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(msg['payload']['body']['data'].encode("ASCII")).decode("utf-8")
        print("Email {}: {}".format(count, full_msg))
```

It prints the first email properly, but on the second for loop I get a `KeyError` for `'data'`. If I try to print the snippet of each email by doing `print(msg['snippet'])`, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`msg['payload']['body']['data']` returns you the email attachment, but not every message has an attachment.

---

- If you want to retrieve the attachment where it exists - implement a conditional statement to verify either `msg['payload']['body']['size']`
  is not equal to `0` before proceeding with decoding and printing
- If you want retrieve the message body content instead of the attachment, you can do it as specified in the documentation